# Are there any reasons not to enable AJAX on a web part?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, ajax

What are the potential drawbacks one would face when Asynchronous Update or Load are enabled for a web part? (SharePoint 2013)

For example, if I use jQuery to make my lists look nice or add some features, will I have issues with the scripts not applying to the reloaded content?